# Ошибка про работе с камерой андройд 6

Tags: java, android, память

Ошибка:

> Attempt to get lenght of null array.

Помогите плиз не могу понять что с этими разрешениями не так:

```
private void CallCamera() {
  File folder = new File("sdcard/camera_app");
  if (!folder.exists()) {
    folder.mkdir();
  }
  File image_file = new File(folder, "cam_image.jpg");
  Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
  cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(image_file));
  startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAM_REQUEST);

}



public void MakePhoto(View view) {
  if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    CallCamera();
  } else {
    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Nu Avem Permis de salvare a imaginii", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    requestPermissions(new String[] {
      Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    }, REQUEST_EXTERNAL_RESULT);
  }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
  if (requestCode == REQUEST_EXTERNAL_RESULT) {
    if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
      CallCamera();
    } else {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Nu avem permis de a salva foto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  } else {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
  }

}



public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  // String path = "sdcard/camera_app/cam_image.jpg";
  // ImageView imageView;
  // imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.camera);
  // imageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(path));
  Toast.makeText(this, "Succes!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как минимум на запрос разрешение использовать камерой отвечает вот эта переменная:

```
Manifest.permission.CAMERA
```

Вы же проверяете только разрешение на запись.

Так же у вас очевидная ошибка:

```
if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
      CallCamera();
    } else {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Nu avem permis de a salva foto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Вы обращаетесь к переменной `grantResults[0]` с надеждой, что в нем будет запись.

```
Attempt to get lenght of null aray
```

Говорит о том, что вы обращаетесь к массиву, в котором нет каких либо записей. В вашем случае длина массива == 0, отсюда и ошибка. Добавьте условие `grantResults.length > 0 &&` ...

Comment: не помогло( я даже задал ему длинну сам grantResults.length ==1 та же ошибка

Comment: других вариантов нет, ошибка при работе с массивом в этом участке кода одна. permissions.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED